# Netbeans downloads schemas every time I use code completion

Tags: xml, netbeans, code-completion

Why does Netbeans not cache the schemas it downloads when using code completion in XML? And why does it take so long? I have a 40Mbps connection so it should be fast. But still every time I invoke a code completion (for example xsl namespace when doing xslt transformations) it says it is downloading it for 20 seconds and then shows me a list available tags.

I know that I can download the schemas by hand and install them in Netbeans but that takes a lot of manual and repetitive work if there are lots of namespaces. Is there some checkbox that I've missed?

My Netbeans is version 7.0.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I no longer have this problem with Netbeans 7.1. Netbeans 7.1 displays a download tab where it shows exactly what schemas it's downloading which is nice.